# Error when scraping TripAdvisor reviews with Python: attractions

Tags: python, web-scraping, tripadvisor

I have been using the code below to scrape reviews about attractions on TripAdvisor. The page opens correctly; yet, I get this error when it comes to get elements from the page:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//div[contains(@data-test-target, 'expand-review')]"}
```

Can someone tell me where I get wrong? Thanks!

This is the url:

```
url = "https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attraction_Review-g187849-d246672-Reviews-Castello_Sforzesco-Milan_Lombardy.html"
```

This is how I get the url:

```
driver = webdriver.Edge(r"...\msedgedriver.exe")
driver.get(url)
```

The main part of the code I use is the following (I am using Windows and Edge):

```
for i in range(0, num_page):
    
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[contains(@data-test-target, 'expand-review')]").click()

    container = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@data-reviewid]")
    dates = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//div[@class='_2fxQ4TOx']")

    for j in range(len(container)):
        rating = container[j].find_element_by_xpath(".//span[contains(@class, 'ui_bubble_rating bubble_')]").get_attribute("class").split("_")[3]
        title = container[j].find_element_by_xpath(".//div[contains(@data-test-target, 'review-title')]").text
        review = container[j].find_element_by_xpath(".//q[@class='IRsGHoPm']").text.replace("\n", "  ")
        date = " ".join(dates[j].text.split(" ")[-2:])
    
        csvWriter.writerow([date, rating, title, review]) 
                
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//a[@class="ui_button nav next primary "]').click()

driver.quit()
```

Comment: Plz add url of the page. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Here it is: url = "https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attraction_Review-g187849-d246672-Reviews-Castello_Sforzesco-Milan_Lombardy.html"

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using selenium, you can directly fetch the reviews from the source code and use review pagination. The review links are in the pattern

```
/ShowUserReviews[-A-z0-9\-_]+\.html
```

This is the regular expression for the anchor tags for reviews.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, I do not understand how to "fetch reviews from the source code and use review pagination." In addition: what should I do with the pattern you report? Do you have examples of code to scrape attraction reviews? Thanks!

Comment: With source code, I mean using requests and beautifulsoup instead of selenium.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying! I will try and see what comes out.